# Trivial snippet of F# code does not work under MONO

Tags: f#, mono, f#-3.0

Here is a bit of code that won't win awards for complexity:

```
[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
   let i = 1I
   printfn "One is %A\n" i
   0 // return an integer exit code
```

It's compiled as follows: "c:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SDKs/F#/3.0/Framework/v4.0/Fsc.exe" --out:numericstest.exe --debug:full --target:exe --standalone Program.fs

Under Windows it produces the expected result. However under Mono 3.0.7 compiled under Ubuntu it instead says:

```
mono numericstest.exe

Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidProgramException: Invalid IL code in System.Numerics.BigInteger:get_One (): method body is empty.

at Program.main (System.String[] argv) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.InvalidProgramException: Invalid IL code in System.Numerics.BigInteger:get_One (): method body is empty.

at Program.main (System.String[] argv) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

What am I doing wrong please? Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your code -- that exception is due to *your* code anyway. It looks like there's something wrong with the `System.Numerics.dll` assembly on your machine; either it's not installed correctly, it's getting compiled incorrectly (e.g., by the Mono C# compiler), or it's doing some kind of type forwarding which is not working like it should, etc.

What happens if you run the code without using BigInteger (via the `I` suffix)?

---

I tried your code in my Ubuntu (12.04, 32-bit) VM running under VirtualBox. The code compiled and ran as expected. Here's the output if you want:

**Compile/Run**

```
jack@jack-linux:~/Desktop$ fsharpc --out:JoeHuha.exe --debug:full --target:exe --standalone JoeHuha.fs
F# Compiler for F# 3.0 (Open Source Edition)
Freely distributed under the Apache 2.0 Open Source License
jack@jack-linux:~/Desktop$ mono JoeHuha.exe
One is 1
```

**Mono version info**

```
jack@jack-linux:~/Desktop$ mono -V
Mono JIT compiler version 3.0.5 (master/1643364 Fri Feb 22 19:31:07 EST 2013)
Copyright (C) 2002-2012 Novell, Inc, Xamarin Inc and Contributors. www.mono-project.com
    TLS:           __thread
    SIGSEGV:       altstack
    Notifications: epoll
    Architecture:  x86
    Disabled:      none
    Misc:          softdebug 
    LLVM:          supported, not enabled.
    GC:            Included Boehm (with typed GC and Parallel Mark)
```

Comment: It works just fine with an int. Unfortunately, I really need bigints. It seems to fail even with statically linked code when it presumably has the correct copy of numerics (already tried a dynamically linked version, same result). I really hope the ultimate answer won't be "wait until Mono matures"

Comment: @JoeHuha - Your code works fine for me with F# 3.0 and mono 2.10.2.  I think there is a problem with your installation.

Comment: Mono is maturing quite nicely, especially since Xamarin cut free from Novell last year. In any case, I'll try your code tomorrow (if it's not already solved) and see if I run into the same bug. That way at least you'll have a better idea about the scope of the bug.

Comment: Many thanks for checking. I tried the stock version [Mono JIT compiler version 2.10.8.1 (Debian 2.10.8.1-5ubuntu1)], and get substantially the same error. Could it be because you are not "cross-compiling"?

Comment: Jack P: I cannot wait to get things working under Linux. In the end, Mono is an enormous project and it's impressive that it works as well as it does. My code started its life under Mono/F#2.0 and all was well until I started seeing bizarre errors from the runtime under both Mono and .net. An upgrade to F#3.0 (then in beta) fixed those, so I am hopeful my code might be close to working under Mono. But so far even simple things that used to work look a bit bleak. It may well be something I brought upon myself, but it's not exactly easy to narrow down the cause.

Comment: I wonder if this is related to the fact that for some .Net versions F# uses its own Numerics.dll and in others it uses the system one and you get some weird interaction there with standalone.

Comment: @JoeHuha I just tried your code, and it worked OK for me (see my edit). It sounds like something is awry with the Mono or F# installation on your machine, or you've run into a very strange compiler bug. Either way, it'd be better to continue this on the fsharp-opensource mailing list, and there are more people on the list who can help diagnose the problem.